# Magento 2 : How to handle array values in custom email templates?

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

This is my observer from where i am passing product name,prodcut price and product quantity in my custom email template file **email_template.html** .

```
$templateVars = array(
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
            'order' => $order,
            'items'=> $items,
            'productName'=>$productName,
            'productPrice'=>$productPrice,
            'productQuantity'=>$productQuantity,
            'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
            'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
            'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
       );
        $from = array('email' => "ramkishan.suthar@ranosys.com", 'name' => 'Ramkishan');
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $to = array($customerEmail);
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('order_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

In my **email_template.html**

```
<table class="email-items">
       {{layout handle="email_product_list" items=$items area="frontend"}}
</table>
```

email_product_list.xml

product.phtml

```
<?php $_items = $block->getItems() ?>
<table class="email-items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="item-info">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items'); ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-qty">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty'); ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-price">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price'); ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php $_item->getName() ?></td>
            <td><?php $_item->getSku() ?></td>
            <td><?php $_item->getPrice() ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: try {{var productName.some}} here is some is "array key". eg: `array([some] => Your product Name)`

Comment: i think it will print only one value. suppose i have more than one element in array than what will i do ?

Comment: you want to loop the values?

Comment: i mean to say if i have more than one element in productName array than according to your suggestion it will print only first value in email template. how could i print another values ?

Comment: could you give example array value of productName

Comment: foreach($items as $item) {
        $productName[]= $item->getSku(); 
      }

Comment: i am passing this $productName to my email_template.html

Comment: Mainly i want to print all the values in email template

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To loop the values in Email template

Step 1: you need to add one layout file in you module.

*yourmodule/view/frontend/layout/email_product_list.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Product List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Vendor_Module::email/product.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2: Create Phtml file in *yourmodule/view/frontend/templates/email/product.phtml*

```
<?php $items = $block->getItems() ?>
<table class="email-items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="item-info">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items'); ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-qty">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty'); ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-price">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price'); ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $item->getName() ?></td>
            <td><?= $item->getSku() ?></td>
            <td><?= $item->getPrice() ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in your email template add the below code

`{{layout handle="email_product_list" items=$items area="frontend"}}`

**Note :** Your template variable `items` should be object

- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento clear:cache

Comment: phtml file is not calling  # MeenakshiSundaram R

Comment: is there anything i need to add ?

Comment: Did you place the files in correct folder? if yes clear the cache and try

Comment: yes i did the same and clear the cache

Comment: update ur code in question

Comment: plz check i have updated the question

Comment: ` $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('order_template')` here `order_template` is email template right?

Comment: then edit that template with that email template code

Comment: order_template is my template id which is defined in email_templates.xml in etc folder

Comment: ""  then edit that template with that email template code   ""  i am not getting what you are saying about ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45573/discussion-between-meenakshisundaram-r-and-ramkishan).

Comment: Error filtering template: Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed
=>Template is calling but but having this issue please suggest me!

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR, after use that code getting this error - Error filtering template: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @sumeetbajaj you should add the object/array in the email template variable

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR Yes i solved already,you are right and thanks for your reply

Comment: Can somebody explain from where this value is coming $block->getItems() because the block here in layout file is: block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"