# Sending order confirmation email template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, email-templates, order-email

I am trying to send an order email confirmation with adding extra attributes values to **Admin**, But it's not working for me.

Here I have 2 Email templates.

1) It's a default email template

2) Customized email template

First one is the default, and it will send Magento by default.

For the second one I tried below code, it's printing as it is table format.

```
<?php

namespace ABCSolutions\AvailableStore\Observer;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;


class AfterPlaceOrderObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface{


    /**
     * Store model manager
     *
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $_inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productLoader;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    protected $_order;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderNotifier
     */
    protected $_orderNotifier;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderNotifier $orderNotifier
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        //\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productLoader
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderNotifier $orderNotifier
    ){
        $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        //$this->_productLoader = $_productLoader;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_order = $order;
        $this->_orderNotifier = $orderNotifier;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,'store' => 1);
        $mediaPath = $this->storeManager->getStore(1)->getBaseURL(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product';

        $table = "";
        $table .= "<table>";
        $table .= "<thead>";
        $table .= "<tr>";
        $table .= "<th>";
        $table .= "Product Image";
        $table .= "</th>";
        $table .= "<th>";
        $table .= "Product Name";
        $table .= "</th>";
        $table .= "<th>";
        $table .= "Qty.";
        $table .= "</th>";
        $table .= "<th>";
        $table .= "Price";
        $table .= "</th>";
        $table .= "</tr>";
        $table .= "</thead>";
        //start foreach for items
        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $_items){

            $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($_items->getProductId());
            $imageThumbNail = $mediaPath . $_product->getThumbnail();
            $pSKU=$_product->getSku();
            $productName = $_product->getName();
            $QtyOrdered = $_items->getQtyOrdered();
            $pPrice = $_product->getPrice();
            $CAField = $_product->getCustomAttributeField();

            $table .= "<tr>";
            $table .= "<td style='width: 120px;text-align: center;'>";
            $table .= "<img src='$imageThumbNail' title='$productName' style='width: 70px;height: 70px;' />";
            $table .= "</td>";
            $table .= "<td style='width: 200px;'>";
            $table .= "<table>";
            $table .= "<tr>";
            $table .= "<td>";
            $table .= "<span style='color: Blue;'>SKU: </span>";
            $table .= "</td>";
            $table .= "<td>";
            $table .= " <span>$pSKU</span>";
            $table .= "</td>";
            $table .= "</tr>";
            $table .= "<tr>";
            $table .= "<td>";
            $table .= "<span style='color: Blue;'>Cust. Attr. Field: </span>";
            $table .= "</td>";
            $table .= "<td>";
            $table .= "<span style='font-size: 14px;'>$CAField</span>";
            $table .= "</td>";
            $table .= "</tr>";
            $table .= "</table>";
            $table .= "</td>";
            $table .= "<td style='width: 50px;text-align: center;'>";
            $table .= "<span>$QtyOrdered</span>";
            $table .= "</td>";
            $table .= "<td style='text-align: center;'>";
            $table .= "<span>$pPrice</span>";
            $table .= "</td>";
            $table .= "</tr>";

        }

        //end foreach
        $table .= "</table>";

        $mass = $table;

        $templateVars = array(
            'store' => 1,
            'orderNumber' => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
            'message'  => $mass
        );

        $from = array(
            'email' => 'info@gmail.com',
            'name' => 'Customer Care'
        );

        $to = "abc@gmail.com";
        try {
            $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $to = array($to);
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('custom_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->_inlineTranslation->resume(); 
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

It's printing table format, like below image.

[image]

Please suggest us to send the email of order email copy with extra attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my self, for the [Reference of Thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136947/magento-2-how-to-handle-array-values-in-custom-email-templates).

create `email_templates.xml` file from `etc` folder and paste below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="available_store_template" label="Available Store" file="available_store.html" type="html" module="ABCSolutions_AvailableStore" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Create `available_store.html` file from `view/frontend/email` folder and paste below code.

```
<!--@subject Available Stores for the Order of : {{var orderNumber}} @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"skin url=\"images/logo_email.gif\" _area='frontend'":"Email Logo Image"}
@-->
<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "Hello Supervisor"}},</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "Please find below order information."}}</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{layout handle="email_product_list" items=$items area="frontend"}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "If you have any queries, Please contact Admin: +91 9949906633"}}</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
 {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Create `events.xml` file from `etc` folder and paste below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="send_available_store_order_items" instance="ABCSolutions\AvailableStore\Observer\AfterPlaceOrderObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create `AfterPlaceOrderObserver.php` file from `Observer` folder and paste below code.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,'store' => 1); 

        $templateVars = array(
            'store' => 1,
            'orderNumber' => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
            'items'=> $order->getAllItems(),
        );

        $from = array(
            'email' => 'info@gmail.in',
            'name' => 'Customer Care'
        );

        $to = "abc@gmail.com";
        try {
            $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $to = array($to);
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('available_store_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

create layout file `email_product_list.xml` from `view/frontend/layout` and paste below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Product List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="ABCSolutions_AvailableStore::email/product.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

And create `product.phtml` file from `view/frontend/templates/email` and paste below code.

```
<?php $_items = $block->getItems() ?>
<table class="email-items">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="item-info">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Product Image'); ?>
        </th>
        <th class="item-info">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Product Name'); ?>
        </th>
        <th class="item-qty">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty'); ?>
        </th>
        <th class="item-qty">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Each Price'); ?>
        </th>
        <th class="item-price">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Total Price'); ?>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storeManager = $om->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $thumbNail =  $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product';
        $productRepository = $storeManager = $om->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
        $totalAmount = 0;
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
        <?php $_product = $productRepository->getById($_item->getProductId()); ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php $product_image_url =  $thumbNail . $_product->getThumbnail();?>
                <img id='image' src="<?php echo $product_image_url; ?>" style='border-width:0px;height:80px;width:80px;'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . $_item->getProduct()->getUrlKey(); ?>">
                    <p class="product-name"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
                </a>
                <p class="sku">
                    <b><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo  __('SKU') . ' : '  ?></b>
                    <a href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . $_item->getProduct()->getUrlKey(); ?>">
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()); ?>
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p class="sku">
                    <b><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo  __('Available Store') . ' : '  ?></b>
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getAvailableStore()); ?>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="item-qty">
                <span><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?></span>
            </td>
            <td class="item-price">
                <span><?php echo $_item->getOriginalPrice() ?></span>
            </td>
            <td class="item-price">
                <span><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered() * $_item->getOriginalPrice() ?></span>
            </td>
            <?php
            $tAmount = $_item->getQtyOrdered() * $_item->getOriginalPrice();
            $totalAmount += $tAmount;
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;">
                <span>Total: </span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: right;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;">
               <span><?php echo $totalAmount ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```