# Magento 2 - How to print array values in custom html email template by looping?

Tags: magento2.3, custom, email-templates, html, array

I want to print multiple coupon/gift codes in the custom email template. I am getting a single code as:

```
$templateVars = array(
    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
    'customer_name' => $name,
    'giftcods' => 'VFDFRVXSW43VF'
);
```

In HTML Template file:

```
<div style="color:#696969;font-size:20px;text-align:center;">
    <strong>{{var giftcods|raw}}</strong>
</div>
```

And output as:

[image]

But this is a single code, I won't to print multiple codes in an email.
I have gone by some related links like:

[Magento 2 : How to handle array values in custom email templates?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136947/magento-2-how-to-handle-array-values-in-custom-email-templates)

[Pass Variable And Output In Custom Email Template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187855/pass-variable-and-output-in-custom-email-template?rq=1)

But there is no proper solution available specially about how to deal with array value in the HTML template.

**Edit:**

In `vendor/magento/module-gift-card` Module this is done as

In file: **vendor/magento/module-gift-card/view/frontend/email/gift_information.html**

```
{{if is_multiple_codes}}
<h3>{{trans "Gift Card Codes:"}}</h3>
{{else}}
<h3>{{trans "Gift Card Code:"}}</h3>
{{/if}}

<p>{{var giftcards|raw}}</p>
```

Variables are sending by **Magento\GiftCard\Model\GiftCardItemEmail.php** as:

```
$templateData = [
    'name' => $giftCardOrderItem->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_name'),
    'sender_name' => $senderName,
    'giftcards' => $codeList->toHtml(),
    'balance' => $balance,
    'is_multiple_codes' => 1 < $generatedCodesCount,
    'store' => $giftCardOrderItem->getStore(),
    ..................
    ..................
];
```

Here `$codeList` is not array. But still looking to solve!

Comment: Pass multiple code in `giftcods` as array.

Comment: Use `'giftcods' => ['VFDFRVXSW43VF', 'code 2', 'code 3']`.

Comment: By this I get error when clicking on email to open in inbox: Error filtering template: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php on line 173

Comment: Use `'giftcods' => ['key1' => 'VFDFRVXSW43VF', 'key2' => 'code 2', 'key3' => 'code 3']`.

Comment: Same :( @DhadukMitesh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100960/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-ajwad-syed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100971/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-ajwad-syed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this to the PHP file.

```
$giftcods = ['VFDFRVXSW43VF', 'FFRFRFVSW43VF', 'VFDFGFGFXSW43VF'];
$templateVars = [
    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
    'customer_name' => $name,
    'giftcods' => implode("<br>",$giftcods) 
];
```

And set in template as `->setTemplateVars($templateVars)`

Use variable in HTML as,

```
<div style="color:#696969;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"> 
    <strong>{{var giftcods|raw}}</strong> 
</div>
```

Clear cache: `php bin/magento cache:clean` and check it.

Comment: I can get codes one by one with this.. for first {{var templateVars.giftcods.code1|raw}}, for secound {{var templateVars.giftcods.code2|raw}} and so on.. I need to print all the codes in array at once!

Comment: above code should work. What's issue are you facing?